# Excel using fraction formatting shows "the value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

Tags: excel, formatting, fractions

Thanks in advance.

SOS.  This is driving me insane.  I'm using Excel 2016 and Office 365 version of Excel (browser only).

I have a worksheet with a bunch of list values - that's all this worksheet is for.  The cells in the lists worksheet are formatted as fraction and some values are (think English cooking measures here) 1/64, 1/32, 1/4, 1/8, 1, 1 1/2 (that's space separated), 1 3/4, 2, 2 1/2, 3, 4, 4 1/4, etc.  So far so good.  However, even though ALL the cells with these values are formatted as fractions (the lists cells and on other worksheets that reference them), Excel is choking on some but not all the values (fractions).

For example, I can enter 1/64 through 1 and the calcs work fine.  I can enter 1 1/4, 1 1/2, and the calcs fail.  If I enter 1 3/4 or 2, the calcs work.  If I use 1 1/4 and 1 1/3 and 1 1/2 they fail.  Calcs work for 1 3/4 but fails for 2 3/4 though.  I can't find any rhyme or reason for this.

I have verified countless times, the formatting of my cells.  I have copied working cells to the non-working ones and that didn't help.  I broke my calculations down into pieces and verified the MATCH and INDEX work fine but the SUM does not.  That's when I get the error for certain fractions.  I even hard coded the values in SUM and it fails when using only some of the fractions.

Here's my calculations:

```
=SUM(A26*(INDEX('Lists-Costing'!$A$1:$X$205,MATCH(C26,'Lists-Costing'!$A$1:$A$206,0),16))/0.5)
```

I've checked the data types in my lists cells (column A above) and in the referencing cells.  The data types are correct.  The lists cells are fractions and the cells where I'm doing calcs are numbers.

Why would excel let me do a calc with say 1/8 or 1/2 or 1 3/4 but not 2 3/4 or 1 1/4?  What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide **as text** (which can be copy/pasted into a worksheet) data that can be used with your formula to reproduce your problem.  Consider reading the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, especially, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW, formatting of cells is irrelevant and does not tell you the data type.  How did you check the data types? It may be that what you think is numeric is really text.

Comment: Hi Ron.  Thanks for responding.  I right clicked on the cells | Number Format | Fraction (up to two digits - 21/35).  Also, right clicked on the cells | Number format | decimal to 2 places.  This is in the browser version of office 365 excel.

Comment: As I wrote, the numberformat does not inform as to the data type. The relevant excel data types for that cell are **Text** or **Number**.  To tell what you have, you need to, in a "helper" column, use the formula like:  `=ISNUMBER(cell_ref)` and see if it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Be sure to check all the referenced cells in the formula.

Comment: Hi.  Thank you Ron.  I thought the formatting was setting up the data type.  My apologies.  I am not that great at Excel yet.

I don't know how to change the data type of the cells.  Each time I try to add data type menu item to any of the menu's they are always grayed out.  DO you know why this is?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please answer my questions so that I might provide you appropriate guidance.

Comment: The cells in question are showing as FALSE via the =ISNUMBER(cell).  

I have been trying to find a way to change the data type for the problem cells but I can't seem to find that.

Thank you.

Comment: Enter a 1 in a blank cell. Select that cell. Copy. Select the cells with the fractions in them. Paste special- multiply.

Comment: Ron...  dude, that worked.  thank you so much man.  Seriously.  Thank you!!!